# Kali Linux 2017 W7 First boot black screen with cursor

Tags: linux, boot, grub

After installing Kali Linux 2017 W7 successfully from a usb, I restart my computer and boot into the hard drive. All I see is a black screen with a cursor blinking in the top left. I've tried mounting the image to my usb using Rufus (both ISO and DD) and win32 disk imager. Why am I booting into a black screen with a cursor?

May be Relevant:
I have windows installed on a different hard drive.
I did not put GRUB on the master boot record, I chose to put it on the hard drive that I installed Kali linux on.

Specs:

- Motherboard: Asus sabertooth z77
- Graphics card: 2x GTX 780
- 2 Monitors

Comment: try running it with the nomodeset parameter on grub. Also try switching VTs.

Comment: What is the nomodeset parameter, and what is a vt? I have very little experience with linux. I also have no grub screen, it jsut goes straight into the black screen and a cursor.

Comment: If you have little experience with linux *you shouldn't be running kali*. Its a specialised distro meant for a specific purpose. [Here's a question on AU to what a virtual terminal is](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14284/why-is-a-virtual-terminal-virtual-and-what-why-where-is-the-real-terminal). You switch between them by using alternate and function keys, and often when X dosen't load, you can still use these to verify the OS works. [nomodeset](http://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do) is a *common* workaround for the precise issue you're facing.

Comment: I actually have a course on how to start hacking with Kali, but the instructor is using fedora with a vm with Kali on it. That's my reasoning why I would like to install Kali.

Comment: The instructor clearly knows what he's doing.

Comment: Do I have the same capabilites in other linux distros as Kali? If so, what would you suggest?

Comment: **Any** distro has the same capabilities as Kali, and none of the headaches. You just need to install the tools with the package manager. Kali is a very specialised distro for a specialised use case. It's not for **learning**, it's not for **daily use**.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I installed kali on my virtual box. The exact same thing was happening. I switched my view to scaled view and then kali appeared. I think you're in the same situation. Boot your system. Then go to BIOS. Change the view to autoscale.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a little old, but someone else may run into this blinking cursor problem, possibly if they are installing Kali on an older computer. This happened to me on a super old laptop, but the internet is amazing because the solution is usually out there.

This is what I did, based on "nomodeset" that was mentioned above. I was able to see to the grub menu, but sometimes you might not be able to. If you can get to a grub menu, just press the letter e right when you see grub. Then scroll down and look for `quiet splash`. Add nomodeset right before it like this: `nomodeset quiet splash`. Then press Ctrl-X to reboot. If all went well, it should boot into Kali. If you search online for "add nomodeset to grub" you should find more answers just like this.

If you can't get to a grub menu you'll have to research why that is happening for your computer first.

You might also want to make this setting permanent so here is info on how (including everything I mentioned):
[Permanent: Coldfish answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782)